# Twinkle not opening after installation

Tags: voip, sip, twinkle

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and I installed Twinkle from the Software Center. When I try to open Twinkle from the whisker menu nothing happens, no window appears at all. When I try opening from terminal by typing "twinkle" I get the message

> Critical: Cannot open file for reading: /home/marco/.twinkle/twinkle.cfg

I was running Twinkle on Ubuntu 12.10 without problems. Basically I just need a softphone that I can use with a Diamondcard.us account.

How can I get twinkle (or other softphone) running successfully again?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Twinkle has been [packaged incorrectly in *buntu 14.04](http://blog.hillbrecht.de/2014/05/07/twinkle-soft-phone-on-kubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/) so I tried a different softphone. I tried [Yate](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/yate) and it seems to be working well with diamondcard.

Comment: How did you use Yate? It seems like this is also just a console app without GUI. I tried `Linphone` on Ubuntu 15.10 and that works quite well (at least for outgoing calls)

Answer (score 1):

The respective bug reports have been filed at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/twinkle/+bug/1297649) and [Debian Bugtracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738469).

If you still want to use twinkle, try to write the configuration file manually and save it as ~/.twinkle/twinkle.cfg

Here is an example of the content in the respective file:

```
# USER
user_name=**UiD**
user_domain=**sip.foo.bar**
user_display=**Your Name**
user_organization=
auth_realm=
auth_name=**UiD**
auth_pass=**Password**

# SIP SERVER
outbound_proxy=**sip.foo.bar**
all_requests_to_proxy=no
registrar=**sip.foo.bar**
register_at_startup=yes
registration_time=3600

# RTP AUDIO
codecs=g711a,g711u,gsm
ptime=20
dtmf_payload_type=101
dtmf_duration=100
dtmf_pause=40
dtmf_volume=10

# SIP PROTOCOL
hold_variant=rfc3264
check_max_forwards=no
allow_missing_contact_reg=yes
registration_time_in_contact=yes
compact_headers=no
use_domain_in_contact=yes
allow_redirection=no
ask_user_to_redirect=yes
max_redirections=5
ext_100rel=supported
referee_hold=no
referrer_hold=yes
allow_refer=yes
ask_user_to_refer=yes
auto_refresh_refer_sub=no

# NAT
nat_public_ip=
#stun_server=**sip.foo.bar**:10000

# TIMERS
timer_noanswer=30
timer_nat_keepalive=30

# ADDRESS FORMAT
display_useronly_phone=yes
numerical_user_is_phone=no

# RING TONES
ringtone_file=
ringback_file=

# SCRIPTS
script_incoming_call=
```

Especially change the values ** **marked** ** according to your credentials and values.

Comment: I tried that and on the console the messages suggest, that it sems to work: "twinkle: registration succeeded", but **there is no GUI**! It seems you have to use the phone on the console?